# When initializing a struct in a loop, why is the address always the same?

Tags: c++, loops, memory, struct, c++17

In c++17, I want to initialize a struct for 10 times and push the ptr which refer to them into a stack. And my code is like this below.

```
struct TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
    TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
};

stack<TreeNode*> s;
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
    TreeNode node(i);
    s.push(&node);
    cout << &node << endl;
}
```

However, when I printed the address of the struct I initialized in each loop, all the address are just the same.

```
0000003F439BFBA8
0000003F439BFBA8
0000003F439BFBA8
0000003F439BFBA8
0000003F439BFBA8
0000003F439BFBA8
0000003F439BFBA8
0000003F439BFBA8
0000003F439BFBA8
0000003F439BFBA8
```

In this way, it's just equivalent to the code below

```
stack<TreeNode*> s;
TreeNode node(-1);
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
    node.val = i;
    s.push(&node);
    cout << &node << endl;
}
```

I know that in c++, `new` is used to allocate a new block of memory for a object on the heap. But I still can't understand why the addresses are same.

I will appreciate it if you could help me or give me some references.

Comment: The address is always the same because its a local variable. Also it's lifetime ends at the end of the loop so storing its address is not a good idea since your storing a pointer to an object that no longer exists. It's undefined behavior to use that pointer in the future.

Comment: Each loop iteration creates a `node` which lives until the end of that iteration. At the end of the iteration, its destroyed and its address can be reused for another instance. Every iteration you are saving a pointer to a *different* `node` which happens to have the same address as an old `TreeNode` object that doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Thank you!  But when I use `new` to initialize the node in the loop, the address is different 
 for each loop. Does this mean that if a variable is initialized with `new`, its lifetime will continue untill the whole program ends if I never free it manually?

Comment: @Rinne: Correct. We even have a term for "forgetting to delete a new'ed object", that called a **memory leak**.

Comment: @Rinne Yes, the purpose of `new` is when you need an object that lives longer than the function scope. But in modern C++ it is rarely used. You are entirely responsible for remembering to use `delete` to eventually destroy the object once you are sure that it isn't needed anymore. There are safer alternatives like `std::make_unique` or `std::make_shared` which should be preferred instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ constructs `TreeNode node` on every iteration of the loop. But it also deconstructs `node` by calling the (implicit) destructor at the end of each loop.

That means the memory becomes available for reuse. And since the example is simple enough, that memory is indeed reused on every loop iteration.

If you use `new` without `delete`, the destructor doesn't run, and the memory isn't available for reuse.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening there is that C++ is wise enough to initialize a local variable just once in a loop. Because it's a local variable it uses the same memory address, and when `node` is initialized C++ assigns the memory address of `node`, and then when C++ checks if `node` is initialized sees that it has memory assigned and skips that step.

If you keep that code you may run into a problem, because you push the address of a local var into `s`, but what happens if `s` lives out of this function? `s` will survive, but the element that you pushed is local to the function, so outside the function `s` will end up with an uninitialized element.

What you need to do is to create a pointer, use `new` to allocate more memory, initialize the pointer and then push the pointer.

```
TreeNode* Node = new TreeNode;
s.push(Node);
```

Comment: Of course, don't actually do this. Use `unique_ptr`, or just store `stack<TreeNode>` directly. Avoid using raw `new`.

Comment: Thank you! In some language with GC, such as C#, if I use `var a = new A()` to initialize an object, it will be destroyed when there is no reference to it any more. Then in c++, if I use `new` to allocate new memory, what will happen if I pop all the pointers from `s`? Will they still exist in the memory and I just can't find them, or be released from heap?

Comment: @Rinne if you use a raw `new` to allocate it then you’re responsible for `delete` ‘ing it.  If you lose all your pointers it will remain allocated, and effectively lost.  As above, use `unique_ptr` so ownership semantics are clearer.

Comment: This answer is wrong. C++ definitely initializes the local variable on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: @Rinne No, C++ does not automatically destroy the object created by `new` when the last pointer goes out of scope. It will keep existing, you can't get a pointer to it and it just consumes memory. But the standard library provides smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` which will implement this automatic destruction for you. `std::shared_ptr` acts a lot like references in C#. `auto x = std::make_unique<T>();` in C++ is almost equivalent to `var x = new T();` in C#. In C++ you have to be careful of circular references, which is taken care of for you in C#.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from cigien is helpful! But there is an argument that if the variable is initialized only for once in the loop or for 10 times in the loop.

So I make a little change to the code and it's like this:

```
struct TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
    TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {
        cout << x << endl;
    }
};
stack<TreeNode*> s;
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
    TreeNode node(i);
    s.push(&node);
    cout << &node << endl;
}
```

Then, the result is:

```
0
00000049F28FF518
1
00000049F28FF518
2
00000049F28FF518
3
00000049F28FF518
4
00000049F28FF518
5
00000049F28FF518
6
00000049F28FF518
7
00000049F28FF518
8
00000049F28FF518
9
00000049F28FF518
```

I wonder if this could indicate that the struct is created in each loop and destroyed in the end of each loop.